# Is it possible to have a encoder to have a different range / start at a different value?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use a encoder for categorical data and I have a process that converts cells below 1 to N/A's. They seem to conflicting because after I convert the category and send it for processing, it turns the 0 of the first item to N/A.

Here's a example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
gle = LabelEncoder()
animal_labels = gle.fit_transform(df['animal'])
animal_mappings = {index: label for index, label in 
                  enumerate(gle.classes_)}
animal_mappings
```

the result is: `{0: 'cat', 1: 'dog', 2: 'monkey'}`

This is resulting in cat to be N/A, Is it possible to specify a digit to start from? I'd look for something like this:

```
{1: 'cat', 2: 'dog', 3: 'monkey'}
```

Comment: I don’t think it is possible to encode classes starting from 1 with default encoder such as LabelEncoder. I think you have to do it manually. Besides, why convert values less than 1 to missing? Does it make sense? Maybe convert just numerical data, not ordinal/nominal variables

Comment: @treskov Thank you. I am doing the conversation for numerical data. I think when LabelEncoder converts categorical labels it turns them into numerics which is impacting the 0 values.